# Should I Split Spring context file

Tags: java, spring, architecture

I am trying to learn the Spring framework. I am making a simple test application.  I have a Client that calls Service that calls a DAO.
The Client calls the Service like this:
XML

```
<bean id="myService" class="test.package.service.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="indexFilePath" value="${indexFilePath}" />
    <property name="pdfFilePath" value="${pdfFilePath}" />
</bean>
```

Java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    MyService myService = (MyService)context.getBean("myService");
    myService.doStuff();
    context.close();
}
```

I want the Service to call the DAO:
XML

```
<bean id="trackingDAO" class="test.package.dataaccess.TrackingDAOImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${trackingDb.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${trackingDb.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${trackingDb.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${trackingDb.password}" />
</bean>
```

My problem is that I have both of these XML pieces in the same file.  So I do not know how to access the DAO bean.  I do not believe I can open the same context when it is still open in "main".  Should I create a second context file?  If so, what is a food rule of thumb for when I should create a new context file?  I do not like the idea of have many of these.  Or perhaps the DAO should be a property of the Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="myService" class="test.package.service.MyServiceImpl">
    <property name="indexFilePath" value="${indexFilePath}" />
    <property name="pdfFilePath" value="${pdfFilePath}" />
    <property name="dao" ref="trackingDAO" />
</bean>
```

Within your service, add a property of dao, like you mentioned.

```
public class MyServiceImpl {
    ....
    TrackingDAO dao; //assuming thats the interface , or use Impl.
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Year! U are right "the DAO should be a property of the Service"!
and   the piece just need one in U Spring contxt xml file!

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${trackingDb.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${trackingDb.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${trackingDb.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${trackingDb.password}" />
</bean>
```

this piece just need one in U Spring contxt xml file!
 Try ! it's will work well!